# Changes in laravel 4.1 routing?

Tags: php, routes, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4.0 my routes file looks like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function(){

    // define the user resource with no system
    Route::resource('users', 'UserController'); 

    Route::get('me', function () {
        $r = URL::action('UserController@show', [Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier()]);
        return Redirect::to($r);
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'systems/{systems}'], function(){
        // define the user resource with a system system
        Route::resource('users', 'UserController'); 
    });

});
```

Which worked perfectly,
because I only passed in one parameter to the `URL::action` method parameters array in the /me route it would use the system-less Route::resource('users...` and if I was to pass in two it would use the system-prefixed version.

But in Laravel 4.1 instead it is returning the route

`/v1/systems/[the user id]/users/{users}` (the literal placeholder {users}).

What has caused this change/how can I fix it?

Both sets of routes are being registered as the output of `php artisan routes` has:

```
 GET    v1/users                           | v1.users.index                     | UserController@index
 GET    v1/users/create                    | v1.users.create                    | UserController@create
 POST   v1/users                           | v1.users.store                     | UserController@store
 GET    v1/users/{users}                   | v1.users.show                      | UserController@show
 GET    v1/users/{users}/edit              | v1.users.edit                      | UserController@edit
 PUT    v1/users/{users}                   | v1.users.update                    | UserController@update
 PATCH  v1/users/{users}                   |                                    | UserController@update
 GET    v1/systems/{systems}/users         | v1.systems.{systems}.users.index   | UserController@index
 POST   v1/systems/{systems}/users         | v1.systems.{systems}.users.store   | UserController@store
 GET    v1/systems/{systems}/users/{users} | v1.systems.{systems}.users.show    | UserController@show
 PUT    v1/systems/{systems}/users/{users} | v1.systems.{systems}.users.update  | UserController@update
 PATCH  v1/systems/{systems}/users/{users} |                                    | UserController@update
 DELETE v1/systems/{systems}/users/{users} | v1.systems.{systems}.users.destroy | UserController@destroy
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use `:systems` instead of `{systems}`

Answer (score 0):

You have two routes pointing to the same action:

`v1.users.index`

and

`v1.systems.{systems}.users.index`

(take a look at `php artisan routes` command ouput)

When `URL::action` function is called, Laravel tries to find the name of the route by looking up in an `actionMap` array and then generates a link using this name.

`actionMap` array maps `action` to `name` for all routes.

So, what happens is that the latter route definition is used in the `actionMap` array.

Use `URL::route` or `route` helper function to generate links to named routes and also pass route parametes with a key, like this :

`['systems' => 'someSystem', 'users' => Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier() ]`

---

[Laravel Named Routes](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes)

[Laravel URLs](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls)